# Render text in "<format>" in jsp as such

Tags: jsp, parsing, jsp-tags

im stuck with a strange problem and im not sure of the solution.

I am getting data from a third party service in form of

> `"TEXT1<TEXT2>TEXT3 "`

and so on.But when i try to render this on my JSP, the output becomes truncated in form of  TEXT1TEXT3 because JSP interprets `<TEXT2>` as a tag and doesnot render it on output as text. Is there any way i can replicate the output as `TEXT1<TEXT2>TEXT3` as such on JSP without making changes in the backend as i dont have any access to the same.

The problem is with the backend service as it is giving output in form of <> tags and not in form of `"&lt;,"&gt;"` 
Is there any way i can get the output to be shown as such, without having to change the backend.Are there any custom tags present in JSP libraries that can handle such behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use tag lib jstl 
add declaration at begining of jsp file

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c"%>
```

if the Attribute is text try this in jsp file

```
<c:out value="${text}" escapeXml="true"/>
```

or

```
<c:out value="${text}"/>
```

instead of

```
${text}
```

You can search **jstl tag c:out** for more information